# Split array of object into subarray on basis of creation year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array of objects like `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4,......]`. each object has its created date Now I want the array to be divide into sub array those who have same creation year like if `obj1` & `obj3` has same creation year `2013` and  `obj2` & `obj4` has same creation year then I want some thing like `[[obj1,obj3],[obj2,obj4],...]`. How can split array into sub array in ruby. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the limited information in your question, I think you want something like this:

```
array.group_by { |o| o.created_at.year }.values
```

The [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) does the grouping but it gives you a hash so you can add a [`values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) value to pull out the groups as an array of arrays.

Comment: Thank you @mu is too short, you made my day.